# Rails don't see paths to the other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I've made a two controllers(users and posts) using scaffold. Then i edited routes.rb in this way

```
resouces :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

While i put `link_to 'Posts', user_posts` (`user_post` is showing in `rake routes`) in any users view file rails says `undefined local variable or method 'user_posts'`. And in posts views `link_to 'Users', users` not working too. What i've made wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `user_post_url` or `user_post_path`. The former is the full URL including domain and the latter is a relative path.

I highly recommend that you read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in it's entirety. It makes all the difference when learning/using Rails.